# I can't perform a single pull-up

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, bodyweight-exercises, pull-ups, chin-ups

I can't perform a single pull-up, or even a chin-up. I can't lift myself to the bar, however when using a low bar (one that I can start from the top) I can perform 3-4 chin-ups but still no pull-ups. What's the matter with me? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you doing the full range of motion when you use the low bar? ( If you do, for instance, half the complete range of motion it's a lot easier and can explain why you do 3 or 4 when you start in the up position )

Comment: @Mårten make that an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exercises are good to build up to performing chin-ups?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/484/what-exercises-are-good-to-build-up-to-performing-chin-ups)

Answer (score 9):

Do slow negatives, start at the top and lower yourself slowly, this is the way most people get strong enough to do their first, clean pull/chin-ups. If you have a rubber band to attach to the bar, that can work too.,
[image]